# autotools finding correct library and function

Tags: autotools

I need to find in which of the libraries (lib1 lib2 lib3 etc,.) a function func() is defined and then also check the number of arguments this function accepts (func(1) or func(1,1)) etc..

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` do determine which library is the first to define the symbol, and you can use `AC_LINK_IFELSE` to check the argument count. Note that `AC_TRY_LINK` is obsolete and you should use `AC_LINK_IFELSE` instead.

Comment: I used this to check the function but it always undefines the label..dunno what is wrong..AC_LINK_IFELSE([func(1)], [AC_DEFINE([LABEL], [1], [Setting the correct value])], [])

Comment: Check config.log.  You probably need to include a header, and it's always a good idea to use AC_LANG_PROGRAM inside AC_LINK_IFELSE.

Comment: thanks that was of real help..but i see that with one parameter as well as two parameters the compilation and linking is sucesfull..i used..AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[]],[[return func(1);]])], [AC_DEFINE([label], [1], [Setting the correct value])], [])..i am seeing that even if i use func(1,1) it always defines the label..what am i missing here?

Comment: Is func defined as a variadic function?

Comment: in /usr/local/include/lib3.h.. i see the definition as int func(int a, int b)...when i run the above test it always passes and sets the label ..the label shud be set only when there is one parameter..after /configure when i do "make" it fails saying few arguments to func

Comment: You need to inlucde lib3.h in the AC_LINK_IFELSE, or the compiler never sees the discrepancy.  Put #include <lib3.h> (or whichever header, depending on the library that was detected) in the first argument to AC_LANG_PROGRAM.